# Sandboxie error on Windows keeps popping out when opening sandboxed browser after Windows Update

Tags: windows-10, sandboxie

I started noticing this problem on September 18th after the Windows Update that occurred on September 17th. I've attached a print screen of the Sandboxie error message, that I need help finding a solution to resolve.

[image]

Comment: What update do you installed exactly?  What version of Windows are you using?  What version of Sandboxie are you using?  All of this is relevant information necessary to answer your question.  Please edit your question to include this vital information required to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

> It started doing it after the update that occurred on the 17th, found out about the problem on the 18th

This is a known issue with Sandboxie 5.31.4 on the current build of Windows 10 version 1903 (18362.356).  Once you install, [KB4515384](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4515384), Windows is unable to automatically start the required Sandboxie service, if it were manually started you would not be able to install programs from within the Sandboxie container.  While the users are reporting their inability to install programs from within a Sandbox instance, based on my extensive knowledge of Windows and Sandboxie, I am going to guess the two issues are connected.

Source: [SB v5.31.4 "The Windows Installer Service Could Not Be Accessed" when trying to install programs.](https://community.sophos.com/products/sandboxie/f/forum/115139/sb-v5-31-4-the-windows-installer-service-could-not-be-accessed-when-trying-to-install-programs)

Comment: Good find, the `Sandboxie` wiki tag or whatever could probably use some detail tho.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - Considering Sandboxie has basically been abandoned by the developer, with plans to make it open source (which have yet to be disclosed), I suspect any tag updates should mention that fact.  In other words, while I used the program extensively in the past, the fact it's been abandoned means I won't be updating the tag.

Comment: Interesting, I don't know much about it but yes I agree, that would be good detail someone like me would like to read about when seeing such a tagged question. I  plan on messing with [Windows Sandbox](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Kernel-Internals/Windows-Sandbox/ba-p/301849) soon at some point though.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - I don't personally believe the tag should exist.  Considering Windows now supports the ability to create a Sandbox with Windows 10 version 1903, the need for a third-party tag isn't really necssary now.  There are alternatives to Sandboxie, which means we would have to create multiple specific tags for those applications, which I think would be a mistake.  In other words since the existing 25 questions are version specific tg Sandboxie (and those versions can no longer realistically be used), the tag is sort of obsolete.

Comment: Sure, but it seems specific to that application though and maybe there's something I don't understand about tags the best, but if I see a tag, and I don't know that tag, it'd be nice to just read a little about what it is referring to with something I'm unfamiliar with. For that reason, I think it'd be helpful quick detail to read about it for someone that wants a quick summary/description, or whatever. If we don't allow the tag, but we do allow the question, then .... and this is where I get confused whether it should or should not be allowed as a tag I guess.

Comment: I know I could easily Google it or anything for that matter but for SU experience of allowed content for a tag that does exist. I'm sure there's something deeper though that I perhaps don't understand ... lol We are gonna get too Meta with it though maybe... ha